# run tests on a lambda container image?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using Lambda container images to package complicated libraries like opencv and pdf2image in Python.

Is there a way to run unit tests against it so I can get a code coverage for tools like Sonar?
With normal code, I could do the following:
`python -m unittest -v`

But not sure how to do that if the code is inside a container image.

I'm using bitbuckett pipelines as well.

Comment: Which kind of tests do you want to run? Unit, integration or E2E? It seems like you want to run e2e, but then you cite unit tests

Comment: unit tests, I will update my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In order to run Unit tests inside a container there are different solutions, and they mostly depends on where you are going to run the image.

1. Assuming you are going to run the image locally and assuming you are proficient with docker, you could build your image including development dependencies and then you could modify the [entrypoint of the image accordingly in order to run your unit test suite](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime). I suggest to bind a path to the local host in order to be able to retrieve possible junit.xml (or any test report) files. This way, you just do:

```bash
docker run --entrypoint="/path/to/my/ut/runner" -v /tmp/testout:/container/path myimage
```

2. Assuming you want to run the lambda remotely I suggest either to bind it to any APIGateway and to perform a remote API call (maybe create an endpoint just for development purposes that returns the test report), or to use additional tools like [Terratest](https://terratest.gruntwork.io/) to invoke the lambda remotely without any additional infrastructure (note that this require using Terraform). Finally note that [AWS Serverless Application Model documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-automated-tests.html) gives additional examples on how you could run your tests inside a lambda.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to run unit tests using bitbucket pipelines, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have knowledge about Bitbucket pipelines, but I think that you should be able to run the `docker run` command inside that pipeline. If bitbucket pipeline supports custom docker images, you could run the pipeline inside the container